# Installing MySQL on Red Hat Linux on the remote server without internet using pre-downloaded RPM packages

Tags: linux, mysql, rpm

I am trying to **install MySQL on the Red Hat Linux remote server without the internet**.

**Problem is :** Can't use internet on the server (so cant use 'yum install ..'  commands)

**Solution found:** To pre-download RMP packages required for the MySQL installation and use RPM command to install them respectively. (so I downloaded the *`Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 / Oracle Linux 7 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Bundle (mysql-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar)`*)

But while **installing these RPMs** using

```
rpm -Uvh mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting this **following error** -

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
        mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.20-1.el7 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
        mariadb-server is needed by (installed) akonadi-mysql-1.9.2-4.el7.x86_64
```

Can anyone help me with installing these RPMs with their dependencies with the constraint of no internet on the server? Thanks.

Comment: Are the other packages it asks for inside the bundle?  If so, what happens when you try to install them all in a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have internet on server, you should download all required RPMs and install it before MySQL Server RPM installation.